# What is meant by data ? - SICP

Tags: computer-science, theory, sicp

During my *SICP* study, I came across a very interesting question: What is actually meant by Data? The book gives the following definition:

> In general, we can think of data as defined by some collection of selectors and constructors, together with specified conditions that these
>   procedures must fulfill in order to be a valid representation. This point of view can serve to define not only “high-level” data objects, such as rational numbers, but lower-level objects as well.

My question is, as today we tend to see data as different types of objects like strings,numbers, tables, JSON and XML representation etc., we are at a level of abstraction that we don't really think in the word Data. So i want to know if the SICP definition is somehow deprecated or we can still see data the same way it is described there.

Answer (score 2):

It's still relevant. It says that the underlying representation is not important. For example, take strings in a high-level language; it does not matter if a string is represented as a contiguous array of bytes encoded in UTF-8, or a contiguous array of 32-bit words in UTF-32, or even as a Linked List, or a Rope (non-contiguous data structures). As long as you can find its length and inspect each character, it's a string data. (The performance might be differ.) All that matters for datahood is consistent API.

Comment: I see your point and i agree with you. My question was aimed to the Constructors and Selectors part, which for me still applies to what we call data but i didn't know if it's sufficient to all the different kinds we have today. Thank you for your answer.